# Why do these two append methods produce different results?

Tags: python, list, append

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

I'm trying to understand the difference between the two methods below:

```
def first_append(new_item, a_list=[]):
    a_list.append(new_item)
    return a_list

def second_append(new_item, a_list=None):
    if a_list is None:
        a_list = []
    a_list.append(new_item)
    return a_list
```

`first_append` keeps adding to `a_list` when called multiple times, causing it to grow. However, `second_append` always returns a list of length 1. What is the difference here?

Examples:

```
>>> first_append('one')
['one']
>>> first_append('two')
['one', 'two']
>>> second_append('one') 
['one']
>>> second_append('two')
['two']
```

Comment: Your names aren't matching .. `bad_append` etc ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `second_append` always creates a new local list for you each time it is called.